# Definition of "timelike"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

Michael Taylor defines timelike in his book Pseudodifferential Operators (1981, Princeton Legacy Library, Chapter 4, §4, Finite propagation speed) as follows: Let $L$ be a strictly hyperbolic differential operator. That means for 
$$L:=\partial_t^m-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A_j(t,x,D_x) \partial_t^{j}$$
and its principle symbol
$$L_m(t,x,\tau,\xi):=(i\tau)^m -\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} \widetilde A_{m-j}(t,x,\xi) (i\tau)^j,$$
all roots of $L_m$ are real and distinct. Then a vector $V:=(V_0,V')$ at $(t_0,x_0)$ is timelike with respect to $L$ if the equation 
$$L_m(t_0,x_0,X+\tau V)=0,$$
has distinct real roots again for all $X$ not proportional to $V$. So far so good. Now the question. On the next page the following is claimed:
" Indeed, if $V=(V_0,V')$ and if
$$\frac{|V_0|}{|V'|}>\frac{|\tau|}{|\xi|}$$
with $(\tau,\xi)$ with $L_m(t_0,x_0,\tau,\xi)=0,\xi\neq0$ then $V$ is timelike."

I can't see the connection here. Can anyone help me please? :-)

Comment: Presumably this is related to the usage of "timelike" in relativity, so you might be able to get helpful insight from that angle. In relativity, we care about hyperbolic PDEs because they're the ones for which we have existence and uniqueness for solutions to Cauchy problems.